# List of all MTP/PTP cameras with WPD

Tags: c++, windows, camera, wpd

For my application I need a list of all MTP/PTP cameras connected to the computer. I am generating a list of all WPD devices on the system with the following code:

```
...
hr = pPortableDeviceManager->GetDevices(pPnpDeviceIDs, &cPnPDeviceIDs);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    for (dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < cPnPDeviceIDs; dwIndex++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But this list also includes card readers, scanner and other devices. Is there an easy way to filter out those devices, or do I really need to open each device and fetch the device properties etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

see this page [WPD Globally Unique Identifiers-GUIDs](http://www.experts-exchange.com/blogs/TheLearnedOne/B_4648-WPD-Globally-Unique-Identifiers-GUIDs.html)
it Contains a lot of constants and declarations you can search for storage or camera ect